# How to loop thru a json strings and convert them to datetime objects?

Tags: python, json, string, datetime

I have a json file with the following content, and I want to convert its string values to date time object:

["2014-01-20 00:01:31", "2014-01-20 00:01:51", "2014-01-20 00:02:12"]

I think I need to create a for loop and iterate through the string values and convert them using strptime method. I'm not sure how to create the for loop so it correctly iterates through the string values.

I think it should look as follows:

```
for items in data:
    dateTime = datetime.strptime(items, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
print dateTime
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What happened when you tried that?

Comment: The answer depends on what you want to do with the data after converting it. Do you want to replace the old list? Do you want to create a new list? Or do you want to process the data in place (within the loop) without storing the new value?

Comment: I want to append them to a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python for loop can iterate over elements of any type (and most containers, notably `list`, can contain elements of different types). It just takes element after element and binds it to name used in `for` statement:

```
dates = ["2014-01-20 00:01:31", "2014-01-20 00:01:51", "2014-01-20 00:02:12"]
for dt in dates:
    dateTime = datetime.strptime(dt, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') 
    print dateTime
```

Comment: Good, but maybe better with https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.util.html#email.utils.parsedate instead of strptime.

Comment: My json has break lines in it. dateTime method fails as it cannot interpret '\n'. How can I get rid of the break lines?

Comment: Use `str.strip ()` to get rid of excessive whitespace

Answer (score 1):

Your loop is fine but if you want a list of datetime objects  use a `list comp`:

```
from datetime import datetime 

data = ["2014-01-20 00:01:31", "2014-01-20 00:01:51", "2014-01-20 00:02:12"]
print [datetime.strptime(x.rstrip(),'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') for x in data]

[datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 20, 0, 1, 31), datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 20, 0, 1, 51), datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 20, 0, 2, 12)]
```

`x.rstrip()` will remove the newline chars